# How to force lambda type to a specific one?

Tags: java, lambda, casting, java-8, type-inference

Suppose I have a function with such signature:

```
public static <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Stream<Callable<T>> tasks) {
   ... submit given tasks using executor ...
}
```

and I have a stream of data, which should be "wrapped" into callable and passed to this function. Naive mapping like below does not work:

```
Stream<String> ids = Stream.of("1", "2", "3");

invokeAll(ids.map((id) -> {
    // Do a long computation with given ID...
    return Boolean.TRUE; // Compilation error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Boolean to Callable<Object>
}));
```

One solution would be to return lambda that returns lambda:

```
invokeAll(ids.map((id) -> {
    return () -> {
        // Do a long computation with given ID...
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    };
}));
```

another (in some way equivalent) is to use helper function:

```
public static <T> Callable<T> createCallable(T id) {
    return () -> {
        return id;
    };
}

invokeAll(ids.map(ThisClass::createCallable));
```

but maybe there is better / shorter way of doing the same? E.g. somehow tell the compiler that it needs to create a `Callable` that returns a given value:

```
invokeAll(ids.map((Function<String, Callable<Boolean>>) (id) -> {
    // Do a long computation with given ID
    return Boolean.TRUE;
}));
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Literally the only difference needed in your first snippet is to change `(id) -> {` to `(id) -> () -> {`. Why do you think those 4 characters warrant a helper method?

Comment: I don't see why you would like to hide the `Callable` part. it's just a `() ->` to add in front of the lambda, so not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! It was a finding for me that syntactically the expression can be written shorter, e.g. `invokeAll(ids.map((id) -> () -> Boolean.TRUE));`.

Comment: Even shorter: `invokeAll(ids.map(id -> () -> true));`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's ignore lambdas for a moment, because I think they're the source of the confusion. Let's use [good old](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awful) anonymous classes:

```
invokeAll(
    ids.map(
        new Function<String, Callable<Boolean>>()
        {
            @Override
            public Callable<Boolean> apply(String str)
            {
                return new Callable<Boolean>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call() throws Exception
                    {
                        return Boolean.TRUE;
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    )
);
```

What you're effectively asking is "how I can automatically do this:"

```
invokeAll(
    ids.map(
        new Function<String, Callable<Boolean>>()
        {
            @Override
            public Callable<Boolean> apply(String str)
            {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        }
    )
);
```

Of course, **you can't**. A `Boolean` is not a `Callable<Boolean>`. So the solutions are limited to what you've already identified:

1) to use a lambda to create the `Callable`:

```
() -> Boolean.TRUE 
() -> { return Boolean.TRUE; }
```

2) to create a method which does this for you. Such as method is likely to more verbose than option #1 so it doesn't gain you anything.

Sorry, there's no way other to automagically make this any better.

Comment: Not pertinent to the answer, but I would also personally avoid passing `Stream` as an argument. It's not correct IMO. If you want your method to convey the sentiment "I'll take any sequence of stuff", you should use `Iterable`. You can create a stream from the `Iterable` in the method if you want.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, but from another perspective "any sequence of stuff" is a stream as well. Stream can be converted to iterable and vice versa – in that way they are interchangeable.

Comment: @dma_k I think the problem with passing a `Stream` is that the caller could have already determined things like whether it's parallel or not. It could even have been closed already. I'd say that that's control that you *don't* want the caller to have. Also, `Stream`s are in general slower so if you decide that you need to improve performance later by using traditional for-loops, you're going to make a lot of changes to method signatures. In the reverse, to improve readability, you can convert an `Iterable` to a `Stream` in any/all methods quite easily.

Comment: @dma_k Streams, like Iterators, can only be processed once and then they're all used up. Iterables can be iterated many times. So Streams cannot be converted to Iterables. At least, not safely, or well.